# Is it possible to undo an hg purge?

Tags: mercurial, purge

I accidentally purged a few files I didn't mean to with "hg purge". Is there a way to undo this?

Comment: Restore them from Time Machine/tape backup? You do have backups, right?

Comment: I don't know why that didn't cross my mind first. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: (I'm pretty sure the answer to the question is no, since the whole point of hg purge is to remove untracked files, mercurial can't give them back as it wasn't tracking them...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to undo a purge.  It deletes files that weren't tracked by Mercurial, so Mercurial can't help you get them back.